# Use 2 named pipes in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pipe

I want to pipe footage to FFmpeg using named pipes (has to be separate audio and video).

However, if I want to open the pipes, the first one works, but when I try to add the second, it fails to open it (just does not finish, no warnig or anything).

I have the program something like

```
cmd_command = ['ffmpeg',
               '-nostdin', '-re',
               '-f', 'image2pipe',
               '-i', 'pipe_video',
               '-i', 'pipe_audio',
               '-framerate', '25',
               '-f', 'mpegts', 'udp:127.0.0.1:1234']

os.mkfifo("pipe_video")
os.mkfifo("pipe_audio")

execute = sp.Popen(cmd_command)

pipe_video = os.open("pipe_video", os.O.WRONLY)
pipe_audio = os.open("pipe_audio", os.O.WRONLY)

## pipe stuff
```

As said, the video pipe opens perfectly, but the audio one does not.

Comment: `'framerate', '25',` should be `'-framerate', '25',`, and it is an input option, but you are using it as an output option. Place it before `'-i', 'pipe_video',`. (That being said `'-framerate', '25',` is the default anyway, so if you want 25 you can just remove it too.)

Comment: Yes, Typo, my bad. But still, theat does not fix the problem, as the pipe_vid is opened without problems, pipe_aud is not.

Comment: Because no errors or log were provided it was a low effort observation in case you were getting the error `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'framerate'`.

Comment: No errors or log are provided, as there are none. Nothing is output on the terminal.. The program just does not continue when opening the second pipe. :/